# Storing flexible schema in Cassandra

Tags: json, cassandra

I am trying to design a new application which uses Cassandra instead of a traditional SQL database. The clustering and horizontal scaling features are particularly useful for my use case.

I have this situation where I have multiple records which could be quite different from each other. For example if I am storing different sport information, for Soccer I would store things like the two teams, the players, results after half time and full time, red cards, yellow cards etc., while if it was a Tennis match it will have things like the two opponents, number of sets, etc.

I do not wish to have a table for each sport (there are loads), and want to be able to add new sports without having to modify the database each time. I want to keep it flexible where this information can change arbitrarily depending on the record's sports type.

How is it best to model this kind of information in Cassandra? I know it is not a 'document' oriented databases like MongoDB etc., but for the rest of the application the 'table-like' structure Cassandra offers is ideal.

I know I can just store it as a JSON string in a text field and process it at application level, but I am concerned that this limits any future requirement to bulk query the fields inside the JSON string (for example all matches that had a specific referee).

I know that there is another alternative to store it as a Map. However, indexes seem to be a bit limited, all examples I seem to find index based on the map key, not on value. And some people seem to discourage the use of indexes on Maps too.

What options do I have?

Comment: If the question is "What options do I have?" then you've already answered it.

Comment: I would suggest thinking of Cassandra as key-value (what it really is) rather than "table-like". Also note that you cannot nest maps, but can if you use opaque JSON-as-text fields.

Comment: @OrangeDog The JSON structure can actually be flat so that is not a problem. My question is more to do on whether I will be driving down a dangerous path by using a Map, whether there are any disadvantages I haven't read about, and whether there is any other option.

Comment: you could think of having sport as a partition key, you would have a partition for rugby, one for soccer etc... then you just have to create column whenever you need a new one. Is it the best options? I don't know, it depends of what you will do with the data

Comment: @Whitefret The key thing here is that I don't really want to bother with creating columns manually for each partition (correct me if I am wrong, I do have to add them manually right?). These fields can change easily and I just want to be able to store whatever comes through for information purposes. I don't envisage having any business logic based on this information, but only returning it via a REST API if requested.

Comment: then why not use mongo? because you want a key/value store for some Json like type no? Cassandra can store json but mongo allow you to query it more efficiently

Comment: @Whitefret I read a lot of blogs where Mongo was discouraged. I am not an expert of Mongo so I have to rely on what I read. I don't want to end up with having 2 databases and having to keep them in sync either. For instance Etsy moved away from Mongo. When I search I am flooded with articles that say 'Don't ever use MongoDB'. Doesn't inspire a lot of confidence.

Comment: In your case, you want to dump Json in a database. For Cassandra or Hbase, you will have first to query the document then make a search in it (or so I believe, I can be wrong) or do some kind of map reduce job maybe? Mongo do that natively. We can think of alternatives I guess, I will look into it. In the meantime, can you link to me your article about mongo?

Comment: One example: http://cryto.net/~joepie91/blog/2015/07/19/why-you-should-never-ever-ever-use-mongodb/ (Through this one I discovered Postgresql actually supports indexing on JSON attributes!) Some other articles are saying that it was just the wrong choice for their app, but the more I read it seems to be the wrong choice for a lot of apps the moment you want to do something interesting with your data. http://svs.io/post/31724990463/why-i-migrated-away-from-mongodb This is a bit older:  
http://www.sarahmei.com/blog/2013/11/11/why-you-should-never-use-mongodb/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115180/discussion-between-whitefret-and-jbx).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Simple a short trick: You create a column for the key and a column for the value. Sometimes you can also use it with a static column.

Like:

```
    CREATE TABLE gameOverview (
        sportType text, sportPropertyIndex1 text static, sportPropertyIndex2 text static, sportPropertyIndex3 text static,
        sportPropertyValue1 text, sportPropertyValue2 text, sportPropertyValue3 text,
        PRIMARY KEY(sportType, sportPropertyValue1, sportPropertyValue2, sportPropertyValue3)
    )
```

Static columns are static within the partition. Sometimes you can't use a static column because the partition would be otherwise too big. (sporttype could be too big). Then don't use a static column but be careful with these columns in your application.

/e Why i used this instead of a map? You can also create value indexes but it's only a secondary index. But as you know is the performance of a secondary index not the best. With this solution you can use the benefits of a primary index but you have also the flexibility of a map.

Comment: But in this case, am I not manually hardcoding the property keys? Some might have 20 fields, while some might have 30 different fields. I wish to avoid creating all the fields. For example if I was using a relational database I could have a separate one-to-many table called `game_info` with 3 fields, the game ID, the key of the attribute and the value, and I would do a `select * from game_info where game_id = 1`. If I index all the fields I could then use some join tricks to get all games played at stadium XYZ.